# applescript - choosed file to path

Tags: path, applescript

I'm writing a script and I need something special:

I want, when I choosed a file with "choose file" to have an variable in that the path is in like a text. My script:

```
set thePath to choose file
display dialog "The path is: " & thePath buttons {"OK"} default button 1
```

So I want to see: "The path is: Macintosh HD/user/.../file.jar"

(if needed: the choosed file is a .jar-File)

and when I start the script I could see the path.

I hope you understand me. I'm from germany and I can't speak english very well :-)

Thank you very much for your time

Comment: what code have you got so far? also see: http://sscce.org

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking. Maybe something like this? This shows how you can add a text variable into a given location into your path...

```
set myVariable to "some text "

set thePath to (choose file) as text

set thePath1 to text 1 thru 10 of thePath
set thePath2 to text 11 thru end of thePath

set newPath to thePath1 & myVariable & thePath2

display dialog "Original path: " & thePath & return & return & "New Path: " & newPath buttons {"OK"} default button 1
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe a very late answer but why dont you try something like this:

```
set thepath to (choose file) -- (or folder if you want to)
display dialog "The chosen path is" & thepath & "If the chosen path is ok then press the button continue." buttons {"Cancel","Continue"} default button 2 cancel button "Cancel" with title "Choose your path" with icon note -- You can make the note icon custom (search for custom applet.icns)
```